# DSRC Implementation in Veins

Tags: veins, 802.11p

I was wondering how [Veins](http://veins.car2x.org/documentation/modules/#80211p) framework has implemented DSRC protocol. Are 1609.2, 1609.3 and 1609.4 standards fully implemented? If not, is there any resources to get their implementation code?

Answer (score 1):

The official Veins website provides these information: http://veins.car2x.org/features/

Veins is an open-source tool available in GitHub: https://github.com/sommer/veins/releases or from the official site (given above)

Answer (score -2):

1609.3 and 1609.4 are implemented, but not 1609.2.